# can we disable right click for a certain folder or desktop?

Tags: windows, windows-10, customization, tweak, windows-10-desktop

Is it possible to disable to right click for only a particular folder of desktop?
I tried the Reg-Editor method but it will disable the right click for the whole system.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to disable right click but you can mark it as a hidden folder so that it cant be clicked at all. right click>properties>hidden>folder and subfolders>apply>ok
to undo open the location of the hidden folder right click>properties>uncheck hidden>folder and subfolders>apply>ok and your folder and its contents will reappear.

Comment: But I have a different concern, I wish to customize my Desktop & I don't wish to show anything else there as well as disable the right click there.

Comment: will this be of any help? just found this https://www.bing.com/videos/search?q=how+to+block+desktop+from+being+click&view=detail&mid=6893AAE7B5E9B5B747596893AAE7B5E9B5B74759&FORM=VIRE

Comment: @SushilSingh that video is xp but it should work similar on windows vista 7 8 10 etc

Comment: I dont find that option in my regediter. I'm using Win10 1803.